# Blogger: Custom Social Share Links With Page URL

Tags: social-networking, blogger

I'm working on a Blogger template with custom social sharing buttons. The problem I'm having is adding the Current Blog URL to the link.

Here is my code:

```
<li class="googleplus"><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=data:blog.url"><span>Google+</span></a></li>
```

If I leave it like that, then when I click to share the webpage, it actually shows `data:blog.url`, instead of the actual webpage URL.

I tried using:

```
<li class="googleplus"><a expr:href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=data:blog.url"><span>Google+</span></a></li>
```

However, that just makes the whole menu not appear at all(even omitted from source).

Is there a solution for this, or am I gonna have to use jQuery to grab the URL and insert it into the link?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use and it works perfectly

```
expr:share_url='data:post.url'
```

OR

```
 <li class='google'>
  <a expr:href='&quot;https://plus.google.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url' onclick='javascript:window.open(this.href,   &quot;&quot;, &quot;menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600&quot;);return false;' rel='nofollow' title='Share this on Google+'>
    <strong>
         Google+
   </strong>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I don't understand how that would work? Is this correct use: https://plus.google.com/share?url=expr:share_url='data:post.url'

Comment: Try this else
<li class='google'>
                          <a expr:href='&quot;https://plus.google.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url' onclick='javascript:window.open(this.href,   &quot;&quot;, &quot;menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600&quot;);return false;' rel='nofollow' title='Share this on Google+'>
                            <strong>
                              Google+
                            </strong>
                          </a>

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```html
<a expr:href='&quot;https://plus.google.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url.canonical' expr:onclick='&quot;window.open(this.href, \&quot;_blank\&quot;, \&quot;height=430,width=640\&quot;); return false;&quot;' target='_blank'><span>Google+</span></a>
```